# How to register a Consul service against a new node?

Tags: terraform

I'm using Terraform to provision new node with Chef and running a bunch of cookbooks against the node on bootup. On certain nodes I would love to register a Consul service on them. The problem I'm running into is Consul isn't running when the Consul provisioner attempts to run.

Am I using the Consul provisioner correctly? Seems I can create service against existing Consul agents but not new ones.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood properly, you have a chicken and egg problem, so it means there is no way to do it in one apply.

You have to create two terraform states (directories).

In the first one you create your servers with the proper terraform outputs and configure the remote state (if you are in AWS, S3 is a good option, if you already have another Consul clusters you could use the consul backend)

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  ami           = "ami-eed00d97"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}

output "service" { value = "awesome_service"}
```

In the second one you use the remote state to retrieve the outputs (I use here consul as a backend, but you could use another one)

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "instance" {
  backend = "consul"
  config {
    path = "terraform/services"
  }
}

resource "consul_keys" "service" {
  key {
    name    = "${data.terraform_remote_state.instance.service}"
    path    = "service/awesome"
    default = "url"
  }
}
```

Then apply the first state and when the instances are properly deployed you could apply the second state.

Reference:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/consul/

https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/config.html

https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/remote.html

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html

Comment: Wow ... I did not know about this. Let me give it a try within the next few days. Thanks. I guess my next question is why the heck is there a Consul provider for such thing? unless I'm not thinkig this through fully but if one is to register a service on a new node, there isn't a way to do it until Consul is fully running on the node.